# Unexpected keyword error in count() when using axis

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm getting the error:

`count() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'`

From what I've researched, this is caused by an outdated version of pandas, but when I run `pd.__version__` I get version 1.2.3

Code where the error is occuring:

```
bdf = df.loc[df['Responsible Party'] == name]
bdf = bdf.sort_values('Date')
bdf['Patient'] = bdf['Patient'].str.replace(' ', '')
num_patients = bdf['Patient'].count(axis='columns')
```

Any ideas? I'm curious if this is some kind of PATH error but as far as I can tell there's no other older instalations of pandas on the system.

Comment: [`Series.count()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.count.html) don't have an axis parameter.

Comment: Isn't `bdf['Patient']` a series so you there is no axis for it?

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Should I use nunique() for this instead?

Comment: What do you need, just count of values in column 'Patient' ?

Comment: I need the count of total patients, so I figured unique count of each would be the best as there can be multiple duplicates of the same name.

Comment: No matter which function, it doesn't have an axis parameter for Series functions.  Whether to use nunique() depends on whether you need unique counts or just entry count.

Comment: Whether you can count this based on unique field of this depends on what's in this column.  If it is a name field that even same names could mean different people then it's not suitable.  Better to use some key / id fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataFrame[<column name>]` returns the column values as a `Pandas-Series`. Count function of Series doesn't have the `axis` parameter like a `DataFrame`.

To get total count of values in the column simply use `count()`

```
num_patients = bdf['Patient'].count()
```

To get count of unique values in the column use `nunique()`

```
num_patients = bdf['Patient'].nunique()
```

*For practical applications I would recommend considering SeaBean's suggestion to not use names as unique identifiers*